# How can I create fake has_many relationships, and have each one include class methods as instance methods?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a class, with some fake relationships I want to implement:

```
module FormStack
   class Connection
      def forms; end
      def fields; end   
   end 
end
```

I have metaprogramically generated classes for both forms, and fields (as they are RESTful resources, they share the same action names and params), and I want to include those methods in my fake relationships in my FormStack::Connection class. can this be done?

I essentially want `<FromStack::Connection Instance>.forms` to behave as if it were `FormStack::Form`, so I can do things like `<connection>.forms.all` or `<connection>.forms.find(id)`.

Is this possible?
Any best practices I should maybe be looking at? (This seems a little strange to me, but I think it's an elegant way to have the methods implemented in a useful way, while still having an ActiveRecord-esque abstraction of the restful resources / objects).

Here is the code I'm working with, if you want to look: https://github.com/TinderBox/formstack/tree/connection_instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a better way, this is how I've solved my problem for now:

```
def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    method_name = meth.to_s

    if "forms" == method_name
        FormStack::Form.connection = self
        FormStack::Form
    elsif ...
    else
        super
    end
end
```

https://github.com/TinderBox/formstack/blob/082793bed97e97cc65c703c8ca3cb382cbdf743a/lib/formstack/connection.rb

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use simple composition? Pass whatever object has the `has_many` FormStack::Form  relation in when you initialize a new FormStack::Connection instance. Then you can directly invoke the #forms method on the FormStack::Form collection instance, or you can use delegation.

```
FormStack::Connection.new(FormStack::FormCollection.new(params[:form]) #sample class name -- obviously use whatever has the real has_many :forms

module FormStack
  class Connection
    def initialize(form_collection)
      @form_collection = form_collection
    end
    def forms
      @form_collection.forms
    end
    def fields
      @form_collection.fields
    end   
  end 
end
```

Or

```
module FormStack
  class Connection
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegators :@form_collection, :forms, :fields

    def initialize(form_collection)
      @form_collection = form_collection
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Would this allow be to do `<connection>.forms.all` or `<connection>forms.find(id)` for example? `all` and `find` are class methods.

Comment: forms actually isn't a method in `FormStack::Forms`, see: https://github.com/TinderBox/formstack/blob/connection_instances/lib/formstack/form.rb